# groupBy not grouping by a tag created with eval after a join

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

- Full details of your operating system (or distribution) e.g. 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.

  - Running InfluxDB/Kapacitor/Chronograf as Docker containers on MacOSX, latest Docker.
- The version of Kapacitor you are running

  - Latest, 1.4.
- Whether you installed it using a pre-built package, or built it from source.

  - Official Docker container

We are running into an issue with TICKscript and its groupBy behaviour.

We have two sets of measurements, indoor_temperatures and outdoor_temperatures, which we query with a batch.

The queries look as follows:

```
var out_temp = batch
    |query('SELECT mean(temperature) FROM yyyy')
        .every(10s)
        .period(120d)
        .groupBy(time(1h))
        .fill(0)

var in_temp = batch
    |query('SELECT mean(temperature) FROM xxxx')
        .every(10s)
        .period(120d)
        .groupBy(time(1h))
        .fill(0)
```

If we HTTP out both of them, they create the following sets of data:

```
{
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "outdoor_temperatures",
      "columns": [
        "time",
        "mean"
      ],
      "values": [
        [
          "2017-09-20T17:00:00Z",
          0
        ],
        [
          "2017-09-20T18:00:00Z",
          11.5
        ]
        ... the rest
      ]
    }
  ]
}

{
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "indoor_measurements",
      "columns": [
        "time",
        "mean"
      ],
      "values": [
        [
          "2017-09-20T17:00:00Z",
          585.44012944984
        ],
        [
          "2017-09-20T18:00:00Z",
          592.94890510949
        ]
        ... the rest
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now we do a full join of them, which gives us expected results

```
out_temp
    |join(in_temp)
        .as('out_temp_mean', 'in_temp_mean')
        .tolerance(5m)
        .fill(0)
```

httpOut:

```
{
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "outdoor_temperatures",
      "columns": [
        "time",
        "in_temp_mean.mean",
        "out_temp_mean.mean"
      ],
      "values": [
        [
          "2017-09-20T17:00:00Z",
          586.10175438596,
          0
        ],
        [
          "2017-09-20T18:00:00Z",
          592.94890510949,
          11.5
        ]
        ... the rest
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Which looks perfect. The issue raises when we want to *round the `out_temp_mean.mean` down and groupBy it*

So we go ahead and extend the script

```
out_temp
    |join(in_temp)
        .as('out_temp_mean', 'in_temp_mean')
        .tolerance(5m)
        .fill(0)
    |eval(lambda: string(floor("out_temp_mean.mean")))
        .as('bucket')
        .tags('bucket')
        .keep('out_temp_mean.mean', 'in_temp_mean.mean')
```

After which the output STILL looks as it should:

```
{
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "outdoor_temperatures",
      "columns": [
        "time",
        "in_temp_mean.mean",
        "out_temp_mean.mean",
        "bucket"
      ],
      "values": [
        [
          "2017-09-20T17:00:00Z",
          586.99190283401,
          0,
          "0"
        ],
        [
          "2017-09-20T18:00:00Z",
          592.94890510949,
          11.5,
          "11"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now only thing left is to group the values by the new tag bucket:

```
out_temp
    |join(in_temp)
        .as('out_temp_mean', 'in_temp_mean')
        .tolerance(5m)
        .fill(0)
    |eval(lambda: string(floor("out_temp_mean.mean")))
        .as('bucket')
        .tags('bucket')
        .keep('out_temp_mean.mean', 'in_temp_mean.mean')
    |groupBy('bucket')
```

After which everything goes awry and we are greeted with `series: null`

```
{
  "series": null
}
```

Is this expected behaviour? A bug? Or something else?

Also filed this as https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/1765 if someone wonders.

Comment: What you've done looks totally legit to me. That seems to be a bug.

Comment: As silly as it looks... but what if you explicitly add (kind of) eval stubs to your expression: eval(lambda: string(floor("out_temp_mean.mean")), lambda: "out_temp_mean.mean", lambda: "in_temp_mean.mean").as('bucket', 'out_mean', 'in_mean') ... and so on ?

Comment: Thanks Yuri G, I'll try that workaround. In the GitHub issue we might have come to a conclusion that it is a bug, but it doesn't hurt to try :)

Comment: You're welcome. Did that work, I wonder? :-)

Comment: Sadly no, but it was worth trying :)